# Want one non-duplicated record insertion but sql inserts multiple records

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table has these columns:

- `int ID` (Is Identity)
- `BusinessFilterPhrase nvarchar(50)`
- `BusinessCategoryID int`

Want to insert one record 'been' and 4 only if there not exists a record with 'been'. The statement below insert multiple records depend on how many record that do not have 'been'. So if my table have no record with data 'been' and there are 3 records in the table, it will insert 3 records with the new data 'been' and 4. I'm confused.

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
    select 'been', 4
    from tblBusinessName t1
    where NOT EXISTS (select 1
                      from tblBusinessName d1
                      where d1.BusinessFilterPhrase = 'been'
                     )
```

It seem inserting top 1 into the first select work.  Any other way to do this without making BuisnessFilterPhrase Unique in the table?

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
    select top 1 'been', 4
    from tblBusinessName t1
    where NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from tblBusinessName d1
                  where d1.BusinessFilterPhrase = 'been'
                 )
```

Just found out this statement will not insert anything if your table is blank.  Note select top 1.

Comment: For each row in `tblBusinessName` that doesn't have `BusinessFilterPhrase='been'`), that `NOT EXISTS` condition is true --> therefore, that row is inserted into the `tblBUsinessName` table. Very basic SQL logic, really ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't select from the table at all:

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
select 'been', 4 
where not exists (select * from tblBusinessName where BusinessFilterPhrase = 'been')
```

Or alternatively:

```
if not exists (select * from tblBusinessName where BusinessFilterPhrase = 'been')
begin
    insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
    select 'been', 4 
end
```